# Memory usage in Android Junit testing (ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2)

Tags: java, android, junit

I'm writing test for my application using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 and robotium, while im doing my test am also interested in get memory usage of my application. 
For now i'm am grabbing the information by looking at the process, but ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 is running its thread on the same process as the app so i'm not sure if the memory values will be correct.

Does someone know how to exclude the memory usage of the junit test, or i need to go with other approach?